# Problem with MAX1645B test circuit?

Tags: mosfet, battery-charging, powermosfet

Please consider the schematic:

[image: MAX1645B Test Circuit]

The [MAX1645B](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1645B.pdf) is a level 2 battery charger.
My problem is with the P-Channel MOSFETs.
There are two P-Channel MOSFETs in the above circuit.

From the datasheet:

> - The source switch P1 is controlled by PDS. This P-channel MOSFET is turned on when CVS rises to 300mV above BATT and turns off when CVS falls to 100mV above BATT. [...]
> - Load switch P2 is controlled by PDL. This P-channel MOSFET is turned off when the CVS rises to 100mV below BATT and turns on when CVS falls to 300mV below BATT.

**My problem:** I think these P-Channel MOSFETs aren't in the correct Source-Drain direction.

Comment: Rasool as in [Rasool & Schneider, "Atmospheric carbon dioxide and aerosols: Effects of large increases on global climate", 1971](https://pubs.giss.nasa.gov/abs/ra00600k.html)??? First global climate paper I ever read! Important one, despite being totally wrong on its main conclusion using a simplified 1D model. Important in that it introduced aerosols back into the serious scientific lingo. Regardless, cool name!!

Comment: i still wait ...